# Extension Faà di Bruno formula

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, derivatives, chain-rule

Faà di Bruno's formula gives an expression for the $n$th derivative of a composite function,

$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(g(t))$,

thereby generalising the chain rule. I was wondering whether there is also a formula available for

$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t, g(t))$,

where $t$ also is an argument of $f$.

Comment: Such a formula surely can be obtained by applying both Faa di Bruno's formula and the chain rule, but I guess it'd be a nightmare to write it out explicitly (at least for me, lol).

Comment: If you are thinking of searching on internet by keywords, I also think, to my best knowledge, that there's no a name for such formula. By the way, Faa di Bruno's formula also has a multivariate generalization which also named the same. Wikipedia has a passage on it.

Comment: I think so this may help https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2000/498526.pdf